# C++11: the type of decltype((x)) and decltype((x+1)) are different?

Tags: c++, c++11, expression, decltype

I was thinking that decltype((x)) give the & reference type, but some experiment showed sth else:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = 0;
    decltype((x)) r = x;
    r = 1;
    printf("%d\n",x);

    decltype((x+1)) i = x;
    i = 2;
    printf("%d\n",x);

    decltype((1)) k = x;
    k = 3;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that (x) and (x+1) and (1) woul all give an "int&". However the running result was

```
1
1
1
```

I expected that the running result should be 1,2,3 as each decltype retrieves reference, but seems only the 1st works, while both (x+1) an (1) gives only int, not 'int&'.
Why, are (x) and (x+1) of different id-expression type?

Comment: If I understand the standard correctly, `x` is an *id-expression*, but `(x)` is not.

Comment: [\[expr.prim.lambda\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#20) Every occurrence of `decltype((x))` where `x` is a possibly parenthesized id-expression that names an entity
of automatic storage duration is treated as if `x` were transformed into an access to a corresponding data
member of the closure type that would have been declared if `x` were an odr-use of the denoted entity.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Where's the closure type in this snippet?

Comment: [\[dcl.simple.type\]/p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4)

Comment: There's also a difference when you have `short x`, because `x+1` will still be an `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x + 1` is a prvalue, so its decltype is just `int`. By contrast, `x` is an id-expression, and so `(x)` is an lvalue and its decltype is `int&`. (There is a special rule by which the decltype of an id-expression itself (e.g. `x`) is the actual type as which the variable was declared, and you have to parenthesize the expression to get at the value category of the expression.)